# Is this a valid strategy pattern?

Tags: python, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I need to augment the behavior of a class using external methods, hence I leverage the strategy pattern.

First I define an interface for the signature of methods:

```py
class ILabel(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def get_label(self, obj):
        pass
```

and an implementation of that interface:

```py
class Label(ILabel):
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def get_label(self, merchandise, obj):
        return self.prefix + str(obj) + merchandise.name
```

And the class that I would like to augment its algorithm:

```py
class Merchandise:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "__a_name"

    def get_label(self, obj):
        return str(obj) + self.name

    def display(self, obj, get_label=None):
        if get_label:
            self.get_label = types.MethodType(get_label, self)
        print(self.get_label(obj))
```

And finally the caller:

```py
# default behavior
x = Merchandise().display("an_obj")

# augmented behavior
label = Label("a_prefix__")
y = Merchandise().display("an_obj", label)

print(f"Default output: {x}")
print(f"Augmented output: {y}")
```

the output should be:

```
Default output: an_obj__a_name
Augmented output: a_prefix__an_obj__a_name
```

Two questions:

- Given instead of an "orphan" method (for the lack of a better word), I am sending a method within a class with reference to self; is this still considered strategy pattern, or a different pattern is closer to this design?
- Since I pass a reference to the `Merchandise` when registering the method (i.e., `types.MethodType(get_label, self)`), the `get_label` method in the `Label` class has a reference to an instance `Merchandise`. i.e.:

  ```
  def get_label(self, merchandise, obj):
  ```

  The question is, is there any better naming convention for `merchandise` reference?

## Update

In an endeavor to provide a minimal-working example, a decent amount of context is striped, which may lead to thinking the `get_label` method can be stateless (i.e., without a reference to an instance of `Merchandise`). The `Label.get_label` is updated to clarify this point.

Comment: Design patterns aren't necessarily universal. They are often workarounds for features not provided by the target language, such as higher-order functions.

Answer (score 1):

> Given instead of an "orphan" method (for the lack of a better word), I am sending a method within a class with reference to self; is this still considered strategy pattern, or a different pattern is closer to this design?

I would still call this Strategy, but keep reading.

> Since I pass a reference to the Merchandise when registering the method (i.e., types.MethodType(get_label, self)), the correct definition of get_label in the Label class is:

This confusion is why you should take a different approach.

Your logic for implementing default behaviour of the strategy is backwards. There is no reason why "a Strategy for getting a label for `obj`" should need to be a method of the `Merchandise` class, except that you happen to have the default implementation stored there. Even that doesn't need to be an ordinary method, since it doesn't *do anything* with `self`.

This means the code is too complex (because you're needlessly using the `types.MethodType` machinery and dynamically patching the class) and also has unexpected stateful behaviour: when you call `display` with a non-`None` value for `get_label`, that Strategy will affect *future* calls to `display` where `None` is passed.

If you don't want stateful behaviour, then you want the default-setting logic the other way around - set a *local* rather than modifying the class:

```
class Merchandise:
    @staticmethod
    def get_label(obj):
        return str(obj)

    def display(self, obj, get_label=None):
        if get_label is None:
            get_label = Merchandise.get_label
        print(get_label(obj))
```

Although we don't actually need the "replace `None` with a default value" pattern here, since we aren't going to mutate the parameter:

```
class Merchandise:
    @staticmethod
    def get_label(obj):
        return str(obj)

    def display(self, obj, get_label=Merchandise.get_label):
        print(get_label(obj))
```

And this toy example it could be even simpler:

```
class Merchandise:    
    def display(self, obj, get_label=str):
        print(get_label(obj))
    # although *this* doesn't rely on `self`, either....
```

If you *do* want stateful behaviour, then you should set the state either at initialization, or explicitly later, or both:

```
class Merchandise:
    def __init__(self, get_label=str):
        self.get_label = get_label

    @property
    def get_label(self): return self._get_label
    @get_label.setter
    def get_label(self, value):
        # may as well do a little verification
        if not callable(value):
            raise TypeError("get_label strategy must be callable")
        self._get_label = value

    def display(self, obj):
        print(self.get_label(obj))
```

Notice here that `self.get_label(obj)` is *not* a method call; Python will find `get_label` as an attribute of the *instance*, *before* it attempts to look it up in the class; having found a callable object, it then calls that object.

Comment: You may find that the latter code looks a lot like a textbook State implementation. There isn't really a distinction, in languages where functions are first-class objects. There also really isn't much at all to the pattern in such languages - all we're really doing is taking advantage of higher-order functions by storing one and using it later. Equivalently, this is just another example of using composition and delegation rather than inheritance.

Comment: `Merchandise` itself looks like a Java-style container for something that could otherwise be a regular function.

Comment: Note that if the default implementation of `get_label` in `Merchandise` *did* make use of other `self` attributes, you could still use it in either of these designs - simply assign a *bound* method (`self.get_label`) to `get_label` in the first approach, or allow the property to shadow an ordinary method in the second.

Comment: @chepner I agree, but I assume the effort to make a minimal reproducible example strips out context that justifies applying the pattern.

Comment: I would like to echo that making a minimal reproducible example stips a ton of context. In my application in particular, other properties of both the `Label` and `Merchandise` classes are used in the `get_label` method. So have a state to both instances is essential, hence I would most appreciate the designs that would keep both states.

Comment: Additionally, in your design suggestion, the assumption is I guess the `get_label` method is only used in the `display` method. However, in my application, the `get_label` method is used throughout `Merchandise` as a result of calling `display`.

Comment: To clarify, I updated the `get_label` method in the `Label` class, please see the updated question.